# What's the relative cost of reading `msg.value` more than once?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate, memory, optimization

Let's say we have the following payable method defined in a contract:

```
function foo() public payable {
  if (msg.value >= thresholdValue0) {
    // some logic..
  } else if (msg.value < thresholdValue0 && msg.value >= thresholdValue1) {
    // some logic..
  } else if (msg.value < thresholdValue1) {
    // some logic..
  }
}
```

Notice how `msg.value` is being used more than once (3 times, to be precise). I'm not sure if that would cost 3 times as much as the cost of a single `msg.value` read, and whether it would be more efficient to load it into memory first as follows:

```
function foo() public payable {
  uint256 msgValue = msg.value;
  if (msgValue >= thresholdValue0) {
    // some logic..
  } else if (msgValue < thresholdValue0 && msgValue >= thresholdValue1) {
    // some logic..
  } else if (msgValue < thresholdValue1) {
    // some logic..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second approach causes more gas, because of introducing `uint256 msgValue`
because it occupies space. I verified both through remix, first approach uses 21195 gas while second one causes 21208 gas. All due to `uint256 msgValue`